# Facing issue while trying to create a table using a query getting errorcode:1292 Incorrectdate timevalue: '2020-00- 00:00:00'

Tags: mysql, datetime

```
drop table if exists d;
create table d

Select *
from
(Select Bill_No, Bill_Date, Amount, Printed_By, Pay_Mode, Cashier, 
        Option_Name, Reprint_Reason, print_date, Print_Time, Settled_Date, 
        Settled_Time,
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,cast(concat(lpad(substring(print_date,-2,2),4,20),'-',lpad(month(str_to_date(substring(print_date,(locate('-',print_date)+1),locate('-',trim(print_date),4)-(locate('-',print_date)+1)),'%b')),2,0),
'-',substring(print_date,1,2),' ',Print_Time) as char),cast(concat(lpad(substring(Settled_Date,-2,2),4,20),'-',lpad(month(str_to_date(substring(Settled_Date,(locate('-',Settled_Date)+1),locate('-',trim(Settled_Date),4)-(locate('-',Settled_Date)+1)),'%b')),2,0),
'-',substring(Settled_Date,1,2),' ',Settled_Time) as char)) as Total_time_Minutes

from audit_report) as derived
```

[Below is audit Report and i have concatenated printdate with print time and then settled date with settled time so that both becomes date and time so now i have use timestampdiff to calculate total no. of minutes between the two concatenated datetiem however i am getting the desired result but when i am trying to create a table from the query i am getting an error.]

[image]

Comment: The error message makes it clear that you have a bogus timestamp literal.  The bigger question here is why do you need such a complex query.  Adding sample table data would help your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My money is on a datetime in a text column in a presentation format :)

Comment: Obviously that is the case, but why...

Comment: Above total_time_minuutes is the derived column using four column and all those 4 columns data type is text here above i am just concatenating date and time and then trying to find no. of minutes between two date time and trying to store the data in  acsv.

Comment: Quite honestly, that is your problem, if you store dates in a DATE or DATETIME column most of this complexity would disappear in a puff of smoke

Comment: My esteemed colleagues Tim and Riggs are right about using datestamp data types in columns.. Nevertheless, we can probably help you dramatically simplify your query if you show us a few data rows of your `audit_report` table and explain what you require for `Total_time_minutes`. Please [edit] your question. Used correctly, `STR_TO_DATE()` is surprisingly powerful.

Comment: Thanks for the above solution its working but when i am doing create table table_name( your query) i am getting an error Incorrect datetime value for function str_to_date. If you want i can share the data aslo after doing some modification in my original data. My intention is to craete a table from this query and write the o/p in a csv file under one folder.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with the comments saying that you would be better served using `DATETIME` columns in your source rather than storing date and time separately as strings. However, assuming that you don't have control over the structure of your source, this query using [`str_to_date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and [`timestamp()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestamp) may be easier to parse;

```
SELECT ar.bill_no
     , ar.bill_date
     , ar.amount
     , ar.printed_by
     , ar.pay_mode
     , ar.cashier
     , ar.option_name
     , ar.reprint_reason
     , ar.print_date
     , ar.print_time
     , ar.settled_date
     , ar.settled_time
     , TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,
                     TIMESTAMP(ar.print_date, ar.print_time),
                     TIMESTAMP(ar.settled_date, ar.settled_time)) AS total_time_minutes
FROM (SELECT bill_no
           , bill_date
           , amount
           , printed_by
           , pay_mode
           , cashier
           , option_name
           , reprint_reason
           , print_date
           , str_to_date(print_date, '%d-%b-%y')   AS print_date
           , str_to_date(print_time, '%T')         AS print_time
           , str_to_date(settled_date, '%d-%b-%y') AS settled_date
           , str_to_date(settled_time, '%T')       AS settled_time
      FROM audit_report) ar;
```

n.b. The decision to use the subquery here is to avoid duplicating `str_to_date()` calls. It would normally be redundant.

---

caveat: this hasn't been tested, and can't be unless you provide sample data and your original ddl.

Comment: Thanks for the above solution its working but when i am doing create table table_name( your query) i am getting an error Incorrect datetime value for function str_to_date. If you want i can share the data aslo after doing some modification in my original data. My intention is to craete a table from this query and write the o/p in a csv file under one folder.